# Customized multiprocessing manager object has no attribute shutdown

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I wanted to run the example code (unmodified) from https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#customized-managers:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class MathsClass:
    def add(self, x, y):
        return x + y
    def mul(self, x, y):
        return x * y

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

MyManager.register('Maths', MathsClass)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with MyManager() as manager:
        maths = manager.Maths()
        print(maths.add(4, 3))         # prints 7
        print(maths.mul(7, 8))         # prints 56
```

However, it gives back the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multithreadingbasexample.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(maths.mul(7, 8))         # prints 56
  File "c:\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py
", line 602, in __exit__
    self.shutdown()
AttributeError: 'MyManager' object has no attribute 'shutdown'
```

Whats wrong?

System: 
Windows 7 64bit, 
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 19 2016, 13:29:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)], 
multiprocessing 0.70a1

Comment: You're reading the Python 3 docs, but you're using Python 2. Use the example from the [Python 2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#customized-managers).

Comment: You're right. Thanks